# how to my local storage value use .css file use jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, local-storage

```
$("#selectBGColor").on("change",function(e){

    var bgcolor= $("#selectBGColor").val();
     alert(bgcolor);

    localStorage.setItem("bgcolor",bgcolor);

     //alert(localStorage.setItem("bgcolor",bgcolor));
    $("#PtmIframe").contents().find(".columns-container").css('background-color',"#"+bgcolor);
    $("#PtmIframe").contents().find(".header-container").css('background-color',"#"+bgcolor);

 });
```

How to use my css file for `localStorage.setItem("bgcolor",bgcolor);` values in `.header-container` class name?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change .headcontainer class using jquery and change the value of bgcolor?

Answer (score 0):

To get the localStorage value:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') != null){
  bgcolor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor')
}
```

So you're code may look something like this:

```
var bgcolor;

// Check if item exists in localStorage
if (localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') != null){
  // Get localStorage item with the key 'bgcolor'
  bgcolor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');

  // Set element css background-color to localStorage bgcolor
  $("#PtmIframe").contents().find(".columns-container").css('background-color',"#"+bgcolor);
  $("#PtmIframe").contents().find(".header-container").css('background-color',"#"+bgcolor);
}    

$("#selectBGColor").on("change",function(e){
    bgcolor = $("#selectBGColor").val();
    alert(bgcolor);

    localStorage.setItem("bgcolor",bgcolor);

    // Set new bgcolor
    $("#PtmIframe").contents().find(".columns-container").css('background-color',"#"+bgcolor);
    $("#PtmIframe").contents().find(".header-container").css('background-color',"#"+bgcolor);
});
```